# Switch two html files every 1 mins

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to create a simple html file that will switch two other html files every mins but got no result.

My thought is,

I have two html files names 'test1.html' and 'test2.html', then I create a third html file called 'test.html' that will load these two html files and switching between each other every minute without clicking or refreshing.

I am thinking of using JS to write a function to do that but have no idea how to do it.

Does anyone have any examples?

Thank you in advance.

Thank you guys for replying with hints and ideas, after working on this a little bit more, I came up this Script to switch between pages.

```
    var location1 = "test1.html";
    var location2 = "test2.html";

    function changePage() {

        var currentUrl = window.location.toString()

        if (currentUrl.includes(location2)){
            window.location.href=location1
            }
        else if (currentUrl.includes(location1)){
            window.location.href=location2
            }   
        else {
            window.location.href=location2
            }               
        };

    setInterval(changePage, 60000);
```

However, for example if I use this function in 'test.html', when switching pages, the address also changed, that means I have to set up the same function in 'test1.html' and 'test2.html' so it can change back and forth.

Is that possible to keep the url always as 'test.html', but the content of the page is swithing between 'test1.html' and 'test2.html'?

THank you.

Comment: You could do this all in one page, just create 3 separate sections, hide all of them except for the first one by default and then show the other ones using [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring different ideas, I got some like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" >    

    var monitorPage1 = "test1.html";
    var monitorPage2 = "test2.html";
    var timeInterval = 1000*60*2; //every 2 mins


   $.ajax({
        url: monitorPage1,
        success: function(data) {
        $('#monitorDiv').html(data);
            }
    }); 

    setTimeout( 
        function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: monitorPage2,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#monitorDiv').html(data);
                    }
                }) 
            }, timeInterval);  

    function switchPages() {

    setTimeout( 
            function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: monitorPage1,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#monitorDiv').html(data);
                        }
                    }) 
                }, 0);

        setTimeout( 
            function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: monitorPage2,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#monitorDiv').html(data);
                        }
                    }) 
                }, timeInterval);  

            };

        setInterval(switchPages, timeInterval*2);
```

This might be not the best opiton, but it with use Ajax to read the html file content and switch back and forth for each 2 mins.

Thank you all for all the helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX for loading the HTML content of each page, without reloading or even navigating away from Your test.html page.

Please check this [MDN Documentation for AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

From high level this is what you need to do: 1. Get content of two files via AJAX requests or include on the same page but hidden to begin with. 2. Create a JavaScript function that is called every minute that either toggles hidden content or makes AJAX requests. 3. You can call/execute your logic every minute recursively like this - setTimeout(myToggleFunction, 60000) Note that 'myToggleFunction' should recursively call myToggleFunction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location='name.html';
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: This loads a file named "name.html" after five seconds, loading it over the existing file. The OP is asking to load two different files every minute, from a third file.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That is right. Thank you. The function replace my previous page and never switch it back.  Charan, Thank you anyway.